# PHP: Why Many Types of String Types And Multiple Implementations Of functions?

Tags: php

> A number of people are unhappy with
>   the current implementation where there
>   are either too many different string
>   types (binary, string, unicode) or the
>   multiple implementations of many
>   internal engine functions and helper
>   functions.

[Minutes PHP6 Developer Meeting](http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#deprecated-behaviour)

This is for the PHP gurus.

Do we really need such functionality?
Doesn't it create confusion?

When I started learning PHP, this definitely did create a lot of confusion for me
but this goes true even today !

So Why at all?

Expert PHP developers, please reply the with the logic behind that.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you add a link to the quote to read up on the issue?

Comment: i have edited the question with source of comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In no particular order:

1. Backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

There is no logic. Php (both the language and the standard library) was never properly designed, and grows chaotically in all directions.

Comment: is that really true sterofrog, i can't believe very popular language started that way !!

Answer (score 1):

The core function names are slightly confusion, and rather inconsistent.

However, they can't be changed due to backwards compatibility.

http://www.bitstorm.org/edwin/en/php/